# "Snow" or "the snow"?

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

Should I use the definite article in front of the word **snow** here?

> I remember snow in late October many years ago

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. A sentence using the definite article might be "I remember playing in the snow on my birthday". An *incorrect* sentence might be "They have forecast the snow for October." Use articles here, the same way as you would for *money*.

Comment: That does not sound quite right to my non-native ears. That snow fall at the end of October is too specific not to be The snow. Shrugg.

Comment: @Cardinal it depends on the context. If you are talking about the weather in general, then a conversation might go "Autumn seems to happen later than it used to." Reply "Yes, I remember snow in late October many years ago." But apart from the question of an article the sentence is a little stilted. It might be better as "I remember snow in late October."

Comment: To my ear, it sounds natural both with and without the article. Oddly, it would be more specific if it said "a snow in late October". That would point to a specific snowfall.

Answer (score 2):

"The snow" if you are talking about a particular snowfall event:

> I remember the snow in October when I was 10.  We built a snowman outside the school.

But if you saying that you remember "snow in October" generally, without referring to a specific event, then no article:

> Nowadays the world is much warmer, but I remember snow in early November, or even in October. That just doesn't happen anymore.